# jQuery clone() printing one time

Tags: jquery

Please somebody can tell me why `output#1` and `output#2` have difference? I have take `t` as global variable and put one js script line `t=$('table#t tr:eq(0)').clone();` outside the click function then `table-row` it is not printing more than one. Where as for  `var g='text-add-<br/>';` it is appending more than one.

Html:

```
<table id='t'>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href='javascript:void' id='r'>+Row</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<b> Text is adding...</b>
<br/>
<div id='d'></div>
```

script#1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var t;
var g='text-add-<br/>';
$('a#r').click(function(){
t=$('table#t tr:eq(0)').clone();
$('table#t >tbody').append(t.find('td').text('table-row').end());
$('#d').append(g);
});
});
```

Output#1 (Clicking on +Row):

```
1   2
table-row   table-row
table-row   table-row
table-row   table-row

+Row

Text is adding...
text-add-
text-add-
text-add-
```

Here is the [working demo for jsfiddle#1](https://jsfiddle.net/nits5457/cahyvr5b/).

Script#2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var t;
var g='text-add-<br/>';
t=$('table#t tr:eq(0)').clone();
$('a#r').click(function(){
$('table#t >tbody').append(t.find('td').text('table-row').end());
$('#d').append(g);
});
});
```

Output#2 (Clicking on +Row):

```
1   2
table-row   table-row


+Row

Text is adding...
text-add-
text-add-
text-add-
```

Here is the [working demo for jsfiddle#2](https://jsfiddle.net/nits5457/fgd4z0ns/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t is a reference to a dom element selected using $(..).

g is a string element you created.

If you don't clone 't' every time you want to append it somewhere, it is only going to move it, since a DOM element can't be at 2 places at the same time. This is why the clone must be inside the loop.

Whereas, your g variable is used to create a new dom element every time you append it somewhere.

See this quick fiddle to prove the point :) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqhqjwso/5/#&togetherjs=RDFLqzneO0)

```
<p id="p1">Unicorns do exist</p>
<div id="div1">There's nothing in here</div>
<div id="div2">Neither</div>
```

---

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div1').append( $('#p1') ); //p is moved
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div2').append( $('#p1').clone() ); //p is copied
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way.
=====
$(document).ready(function(){
var t;
var g='text-add-<br/>';
t=$('table#t tr:eq(0)').clone();
$('a#r').click(function(){
$('table#t >tbody').append(t.find('td').text('table-row').end());
$('#d').append(g);
});
});
=======
t=$('table#t tr:eq(0)').clone();
it is set to one time and we can use it multiple time to insert ($('table#t >tbody').append(t.find('td').text('table-row').end());
$('#d').append(g);).?

Comment: I guess you could either convert get the whole element as a string.
(a wrap is needed since html() returns the content)
var str = $(selector).clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
    
OR    
    
create a getMyClone() function which will return a clone.

Comment: Though I would like your reasoning for doing so?

Comment: Basically, I have to clone the table tr so that I can append tr in other element id. it will be generic code means if tr columns changes/modify then its clone will be append. 
Case: I have a table#a if user select the one tr then ajax call occur then we dont show that record in table#a. I have to show that record in table#b this table#b is making dyanamically. When user click on table#a tr I clone the tr and when ajax request successfull then I show that clone tr in table#b. ( that part is working.) getting problem when i want to make empty td with clone and append in table#b.